# Script to create checkpoints on multiple servers in SCVMM

Tags: powershell, foreach, hyper-v

I am using a standard script to take a singular checkpoint in SCVMM of a VM. It is:

```
Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name 'servername' | New-SCVMCheckpoint
```

I am also using:

```
Checkpoint-VM -Name Test -SnapshotName BeforeInstallingUpdates
```

I'd like to use either command to checkpoint serveral vm's, using a foreach command. Can someone walk me through adding that in?

I have a text file at `c:\temp\checkpoint.txt`

So I was thinking something like:

```
$vms = "c:\temp\checkpoint.txt"
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name '$vms' | New-SCVMCheckpoint
}
```

Just not 100% sure
Any assistance and knowledge share is greatly appreciated

Comment: PLEASE, wrap your code [& any data or sample text] in code formatting markers. you can find the instructions for that in a link on the page you used to create your Question.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you posted you are looping around the string `c:\temp\checkpoint.txt`

You will first need to actually get the list of server names from the text file like this:

```
$vms = Get-Content "c:\temp\checkpoint.txt"
```

But how exactly you do that will depend on how that file is formatted

The above will work fine if you file looks like this:

```
vmname-1
vmname-2
vmname-3
    ... etc
```

---

Once you have the list of VM names, you need to change your foreach loop to look more like this:

```
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name $vm | New-SCVMCheckpoint
}
```

- Note that I removed the `'`s from around the variable name in the executing line. As soon as you add the quotes around some text, it becomes a string and is no longer a variable. You could achieve this with double quotes (`"`) but in this case they are not needed!
- On the line where you call `Get-SCVirtualMachine` it should be `$vm` not `$vms`, since the latter is the entire collection, where you only want to use the particular vm we are currently looking at in the loop!

Have a look at [SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html) for some great notes and example on PowerShell commands